# How can I can predict the behavior of this falling system of particles?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, lagrangian-formalism

Consider a system of particles like this:
[image: System of particles at ]initial time[1]]

It has 5 particles (A, B, C, D and E).

The particle A and E are on a pole, so they're being prevented to fall down. And consequently, their height is fixed in time.

However, particles B, C, D are free to move.

All particles are connected via massless rods and can rotate around. For instance B is free to rotate around A and C. And that is true for all particles.

The initial distance between A to E is $d$. The distance between each particle (for instance, A to B) is $d/4$. That is why, initially ($t=0$) these particles are in the air and not falling down.

Then, at time $t$, the distance between the poles (A and E) is $d-t$.

So, as you can imagine the whole system will start to fall, each particle will rotate around another in some fashion. Now in order to predict it's behavior at time $t$ we need an expression of force on each individual particle. Since A and E move at a constant velocity on their poles, we need three expressions, $F_B$, $F_C$ and finally $F_D.$ Even from these three, one is redundant due to the symmetry of the problem. The force expression for B will be exactly the same as D except for the reverse sign in x-direction.

So, the problem is reduced down to figuring out the $F_D$ and $F_C$. Because then, of course we have the differential equation that we can solve.

I have been banging my head against the wall for some time now, trying to figure out what these $F_D$ and $F_C$ are? I know, for example, that the force on particle D will be due to E, C, B, and A, but how does one go about coming up with such an expression?

All of these particles have the same mass $m$ and their initial height is $h$.

Let me know if I missed out some important piece of information or if more clarity is required.

Comment: What do you mean they are on a mass less rod?

Comment: Like a pendulum's rod whose mass is negligible compared to the mass of the particle.

Comment: So you mean rope. Ergo the  particles are fixed to a catenary. .. I am not sure catenary Is correct in English.  I mean the func describing a rope or chain suspended at two points.  Your system seems to reduce to that  it seems so to me. It is basically a chain ( catena in my language)

Comment: No, not a rope. And the knowledge about catenary being the curve that fits these system of particles cannot be applied here I am specifically asking about the forces and weather or not an expression for them can be written.

Comment: Got the description, at least.

Comment: Can the rods extend? If not then there isn't a valid solution.

Comment: What do you mean by extend?

Comment: Do they stretch? Alternatively, do the poles bend?

Comment: Poles do not stretch. These poles are rigid. These particles will rotate around like pendulums.

Comment: Think of double pendulum, and extend that idea in your head to this.

Comment: The rods are a fixed length and pin-jointed at the masses A-E.

Answer (score 1):

The setup looks like this for time $t>0$:

[image: Diagram after motion starts]

The masses A-E are labeled the same as in the question, the rod lengths are all $d/4$ where $d$ is the starting distance between the two poles. The distance between the poles now is labeled $L$ and is a function of time $L(t) = d - t$. The lowercase letters $b$ and $c$ indicate the angle from horizontal of the rods to the left of masses B and C.

In a static situation with $L$ unchanging, all of the forces on the masses have to sum to zero. Starting from the middle:
$$F_{Cy} = 2T_c\sin c - mg = 0 \quad (1)$$
where $F_y$ is the total vertical force on mass C, $T_c$ is the tension in the rod to the left $c$ (and right, by symmetry), $m$ is the mass of C (and A, B, D, and E), and $g$ is the acceleration due to gravity. By symmetry, we already know that the horizontal forces cancel.

Now for mass B:
$$F_{By} = T_b\sin b - T_c\sin c - mg = 0 \quad (2)$$
$$F_{Bx} = -T_b\cos b + T_c\cos c = 0. \quad (3)$$
where $F_{By}$ is the total vertical force on B and $F_{Bx}$ is the total horizontal force on B. The rest variables here are defined similarly to Equation (1). The signs are chosen so that positive indicates up and to the right. Note that, as $b$ and $c$ go to zero (the state of the drawing in the original question), the tension in the rods goes to infinity, since a horizontal rod cannot provide a vertical force with just tension.

Now, we have four unknowns ($b$, $c$, $T_b$, $T_c$) and three equations.  This last equation is purely geometric, in that the horizontal position of C if halfway between the poles.
$$\frac{d}{4}\cos b + \frac{d}{4}\cos c = \frac{L}{2}. \quad (4)$$
From this you can solve for the positions of all the masses.

Now, from your question, it sounds like you want expressions for the dynamic forces on the masses as the poles move. This is a much hairier problem and is just as chaotic as the double pendulum. It can be analyzed with [Lagrangian mechanics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrangian_mechanics) and using $b$, $c$, and $L$ as your generalized coordinates.

Comment: Cannot we use the catenary equation? First i got that idea. Now I am unsure without studying the details for catenary and if assumptions still work here.

Comment: @Alchimista A catenary will result from taking the limit of the above problem as the number of masses goes to infinity will keeping the total mass constant.

Comment: It's not clear to me how you got equation 2 and 3. In eq 2 you wrote down gravity term + tension on b + on c. First of all, how do you know that the force will simply be the sum of them and secondly, shouldn't there be a D term too. Can you please clarify?

Comment: I first did tgis for 1 particle in the center and then 2 and I got stuck for 3. You seemed to have solved it. I haven't completely understood you solution which I will eventually. I want to know if the same method could be applied for 4, 5, 6 particles. And eventually for n particles.

Comment: I see it graphically . If we take infinite masses and fix total length is also mathematically evident that it then a catenary.  I still wonder if the positions of each masses is stuck to a catenary even here. Meantime writing this I also see it. In a catenary p B will be lower and C higher :)

Comment: @Anonymous The total force on a mass is the sum of each individual force. When you add forces, you add the vertical components together and the horizontal components together separately. You only consider the forces that directly act on a mass, so mass B is only affected by gravity and the tensions from the two adjacent rods. Tension $T_c$ is the tension from the rod to the right of C, which acts on both masses B and C. As for D, due to symmetry, we can see that mass D will behave the same as mass B.